# error: package org.xwalk.core does not exist Android Studio & Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, crosswalk-runtime

Me and a colleague have been stuck on this issue for the past 2 days. We have to get CrossWalk integrated into an Android Studio project we built with Cordova.

We have our structure set up the standard way as follows:

[image]

We have our build.gradle file for the application setup as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    if (multiarch || System.env.BUILD_MULTIPLE_APKS) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}

def getVersionCodeFromManifest() {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
}

def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}
```

the settings.gradle file for our project is as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}

for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
    include subproject
}

include ':'
```

the project properties file is:

```
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
```

The build.gradle file for CordovaLib is setup as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

There was only one issue I could find, and their explanation was about adding dependencies to our gradle files (none of which worked). If you have any idea what we are missing or overlooking, your exquisite expertise is much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of crosswalk? Version 11+ requires API level 21 instead of 19.

Comment: Ya the problem is that it can't find org.xwalk at all. The API level is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have included the cordova project incorrectly. See: [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)